# Xslt abs function?

Tags: xslt, function

I an trying to transform some data. The data contained in my xml field "Source/End/Edgecode"  looks like -000016
I want to remove the leading dash. I thought I could use abs or right, but I don't know the correct syntax.
Thanks for any help...
        
            
        
         
        
            
        
         
        
         
        
        
* FROM CLIP NAME:

```
<xsl:template name="frame_to_tc">
    <xsl:param name="frame"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hh" select="($frame div $fph)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rh" select="($frame mod $fph)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="($rh div $fpm)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rm" select="($rh mod $fpm)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ss" select="($rm div $fps)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rs" select="($rm mod $fps)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ff" select="($rs mod $fps)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($hh),'00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($mm),'00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($ss),'00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($ff),'00')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple substring.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($yourVariable, 2)"/>
<!-- In XSLT, the index starts from 1, so here you are taking a substring starting from the second character, in essence, leaving out the hyphen-->
```

Or even the node directly instead of the variable..

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/Your/Path/Here, 2)"/>
```

Since you are not specifying a specific number of characters to return, it will return the rest of the string completely. You can restrict the number of characters returned which is done by adding a comma and then specifying a second length upto which to cut) Ex: `substring(/Your/Path/Here , 2, 5)`

This will cut from the 2nd character upto five characters, If the string is "1234567" it will return "23456".

NOTE: This is assuming that you only want to remove the leading hyphen. If you want to remove the leading zeroes as well, a number() typecast should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template name="abs">
  <xsl:param name="input" select="0">

  <xsl:variable name="num" select="number(input)" />    
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$num &gt;= 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$num" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$num &lt; 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="-1 * $num" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
<xsl:template>
```

callable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="absnum">
  <xsl:call-template name="abs">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="some/number" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the leading dash, try [this XPath function](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-after.html):

```
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($x,'-')"/>
```

Comment: What happens if the '-' is missing? :)

Comment: yeh, this was an offhand solution. This assumes EVERY string has a - somewhere in it.